# Golang: Why does regexp.FindAllStringSubmatch() returns [][]string and not []string?

Tags: regex, go

I am kind of new to go and that's the first time I have to deal with regexp.

I am a bit surprised that the `someregex.FindAllStringSubmatch("somestring", -1)` returns a slice of slice `[][]string` instead of a simple slice of string : `[]string`.

example :

```golang
someRegex, _ := regexp.Compile("^.*(mes).*$")
matches := someRegex.FindAllStringSubmatch("somestring", -1)
fmt.Println(matches) // logs [[somestring mes]]
```

What is the reason of this behavior, I can't figure it out ?

Comment: Because it needs a place to store *submatches*, i.e. groups defined in the pattern with pairs of unescaped parentheses.

Comment: what do you mean ?

Comment: Have you read https://golang.org/pkg/regexp/#Regexp.FindAllStringSubmatch? Did you  try the example? Your example regex matches the whole string and captures `mes`. There must be a place for a match and the capture, right?

Comment: Yes I did read this, but I didn't think to try the examples, that's clearer now, thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [`func (*Regexp) FindAllStringSubmatch`](https://golang.org/pkg/regexp/#Regexp.FindAllStringSubmatch) extracts matches and *captured* submatches.

A submatch is a part of the text that is matched by the regex part that is enclosed with a pair of unescaped parentheses (a so called [**capturing group**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)).

In your case, `^.*(mes).*$` matches:

- `^` - start of string
- `.*` - any 0+ chars as many as possible
- `(mes)` - **Capturing group 1**: a `mes` substring
- `.*$`  - the rest of the string.

So, the match value is the whole string. It will be the first value in the output. Then, since there is a capturing group, there must be a place for it in the results, hence, `mes` is placed as the second item in the list.

Since there may be more matches than 1, we need a list of lists.

A better example may be the one with several match / submatch extraction (and maybe an optional group, too):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
    someRegex, _ := regexp.Compile(`[^aouiye]([aouiye])([^aouiye])?`)
    matches := someRegex.FindAllStringSubmatch("somestri", -1)
    fmt.Printf("%q\n", matches)
}
```

The `[^aouiye]([aouiye])([^aouiye])?` matches a non-vowel, a vowel, and a non-vowel, capturing the last 2 into separate groups  #1 and #2.

The results are `[["som" "o" "m"] ["ri" "i" ""]]`. There are 2 matches, and each contains a match value, Group 1 value and Group 2 value. Since the `ri` match has no text captured into Group 2 (`([^aouiye])?`), it is empty, but it is still there since the group is defined in the regex pattern.

Answer (score 3):

> FindAllStringSubmatch is the 'All' version of FindStringSubmatch; it
>   returns a slice of all successive matches of the expression, as
>   defined by the 'All' description in the package comment. A return
>   value of nil indicates no match.

[Docs](https://golang.org/pkg/regexp/#Regexp.FindAllStringSubmatch).

To sum up: You need an array of arrays of strings, because this is the all version of FindStringSubmatch. FindStringSubmatch will return a single string array.